# how to update formik input value using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a state `const [minVal, setValue] = useState('')`
I have a function `const valueChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value)`
I have input field inside formik `<input value={minVal} onChange={e => e.handleChange(e); valueChange(e)}  />`
**I am not able to update value using state using above method**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
const [minVal, setValue] = useState('')

const valueChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value)

<input value={minVal} onChange={e => valueChange(e)}  />
```

`e.handleChange` is not a function. So at this point react will throw an error and the next line of the code (where you are actually updating the state) will not execute.

Please read form handling in react here https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: No, I am using formik which needs handleChange to be used before we pass any custom handlechange function.